# I can't open NuGet Package Manager for a project that i cloned from git

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package

I cloned my repo to git at work, but when I cloned it to my home computer, I wasn't able to reach nuget package manager, when i right click to the solution there is no option for nuget. Is there a way for me to get my git clone work like the original?

Comment: What error do you get during the build? You mean the nuget options are not available from the solution and project context menus in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Just close the visual studio. Open the project folder and then open `.csproj` file using visual studio. Then you will see context specific menus.

Comment: Why should that help? The nuget operations are supposed to work on the whole solution as well, so you can update a package that is used in many projects at once.

Comment: @PMF I just provided the solution for problem. Try it out create console app using this `dotnet new console -o myProject` and open the project in visual studio by selecting the project folder. You will have exact problem as above.

Comment: Ah, ok. Never opened a "project" that way. I thought the OP correctly had a solution open, since that's what he writes.

Answer (score 0):

Start Visual Studio or Visual Web Developer Express as an Administrator.
In the Tools menu of Visual Studio, select Extension Manager.
In the Extension Manager dialog box, click the Uninstall button for NuGet Package Manager. If NuGet-Based Package Manager doesn't appear, NuGet isn't installed.
Follow the links below to troubleshoot NuGet-Based Package Manager

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio

Comment: That extension is not necessary for the feature the OP is looking for.